# Getting Blank Email

Tags: javascript, php, email

I am trying to create a email form that does not redirect to another other page. I am a newbie at PHP and Javascript .. so basically i have coded like this -

I have included the following code in the mail.php file

```html
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "devtest@xxx.org";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='test.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

I have uploaded all the files to web server but the problem is that when I am sending test emails, I am not getting blank emails.

The email only contains name of the sender and the email id.

Please let me know where I am messing things up.

```
<div class="contact">
  <div class="contact-wrap">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function verify() {
        if (document.getElementById("name").value == "" || document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
          alert("Please enter a name and an email.");
        } else {
          alert("Looks good, sending email");
          //document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit();
          var name = $('#name').val();
          var email = $('#email').val();
          var formData = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email;
          $.ajax({
            url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              //data - response from server
              alert(data);
            },

          });
        }
      }
    </script>

    <div class="quick-contact">
      <form action="#" id="ContactForm" method="post" action="mail.php">

        <p>Your Name (required) <br>
          <input type="text" class="form-bt" value="" size="40" name="name" id="name" required>
        </p>

        <p>Your Email (required) <br>
          <input type="email" class="form-bt" value="" size="40" name="email" id="email" required>
        </p>

        <p>Subject <br>
          <input type="text" class="form-bt" value="" name="phone" size="40">
        </p>

        <p>Your Message<br>
          <textarea cols="40" rows="10" class="text-area" name="message" required></textarea>
        </p>

        <p>
          <input type="submit" id="send" onClick="verify()" value="Send" class="btton" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'black'" ; onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = '#74b9e4'" ;>
        </p>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

kind regards
deb

Comment: Please use below code `$respMail = mail(); if(!$respMail){print_r(error_get_last());}`. This code will represent the error if any. And `print_r($_POST);`. for check every variable values that you are using.

Comment: If your form is web facing guard against email injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just sent email and name. Replace

```
var  formData = "name="+name+"&email="+email;
```

to

```
var  formData = "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message;
```

Also get message variable as :

```
var message=$('#message').val();
```

And change the textarea to :

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="10" class="text-area" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting form data with name and email only.

```
var  formData = "name="+name+"&email="+email;
```

Add fields as necessary.
Also a good way to do this is:

```
var formData = {
    name : $('#name').val(),
    email : $('#email').val(),
    message : $('#message').val() //Say ID for your message is "message"
}
```

rather than:

```
var  formData = "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message;
```